# How to programmatically add a custom field to Address?

Tags: 8

I'm using [Address module](https://www.drupal.org/project/address), and I need to add a Boolean field "Handicap access" for all addresses, whichever country is selected.

I digged into module issues, I carefully read [provided docs](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/customers/addresses), where there is an example about how to : *Create a custom address field by repurposing an unused one*.

> What about address field X? Can I add another property to an address
>   field?
>
> No, not without great difficulty. But you can repurpose an unused
>   property for a custom one.

But there is not any boolean existing field into Address fields. Any tip to put me on the right track is welcome. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your specific problem, but you can create a custom paragraph type with an address field and a boolean field, then add a Paragraph Entity field on your content type. You can limit this paragraph reference field to your newly created paragraph type. This will allow you to have a field with both address/accessibility information.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Gavin. This project is currently not using Paragraph, and if possible I'd prefer to stick to a coding solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since Address module field names [follow the OASIS eXtensible Address Language (xAL) standard](https://github.com/commerceguys/addressing/blob/master/README.md), I had a look at xAL standard itself but could not find a way to add a *disabled access* field properly following this standard.

So I stuck to the provided doc, not that bad in fact : instead of a boolean customers may have more informations :

In `mymodule.services.yaml`

```
mymodule.subscriber:
  class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\DisabledAccessEventSubscriber
  tags:
    - {name: event_subscriber}
```

In `mymodule\EventSubscriber\DisabledAccessEventSubscriber.php`

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\address\Event\AddressEvents;
use Drupal\address\Event\AddressFormatEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class DisabledAccessEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[AddressEvents::ADDRESS_FORMAT][] = ['onAddressFormat'];
    return $events;
  }

  public function onAddressFormat(AddressFormatEvent $event) {
    $definition = $event->getDefinition();

    $format = $definition['format'];
    $format = str_replace('%additionalName', '', $format);
    $format = str_replace('%addressLine2', "%addressLine2\n%additionalName", $format);
    $definition['format'] = $format;

    $event->setDefinition($definition);
  }

}
```

In `mymodule.module`

```
/**
 * Modifies Address format to add a PMR field
 */
function mymodule_customize_address($element, $form_state) {
  $element['additional_name']['#title'] = t('Disabled access');
  $element['additional_name']['#description'] = t(
    'Give your customers some details about your store accessibility');

  return $element;
}
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (($form_id == 'profile_foo_profile_edit_form')) {
    foreach ($form['field_profile_address']['widget'] as $key => $value) {
      if (is_numeric($key)) {
        $form['field_profile_address']['widget'][$key]['address']['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_customize_address';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Be what it is, I'll be glad if somebody's able to explain me how to extend Address and add a field to default ones.